# Simplifying Expression of Combinations

Tags: combinations

How do you simplify this equation:

$\dbinom{n}{k}-\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}-\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}$

I simplified it to this:

$\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}-\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}-\dfrac{(n-2)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}$

but I'm stuck on what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pascal's Indentity twice:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\dbinom{n}{k}-\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}-\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}&=&\dbinom{n}{k}-\left[\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-2}{k}\right]+\dbinom{n-2}{k}\\
&=&\dbinom{n}{k}-\left[\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-1}{k}\right]+\dbinom{n-2}{k}\\
&=&\dbinom{n}{k}-\dbinom{n}{k}+\dbinom{n-2}{k}\\
&=&\dbinom{n-2}{k}\\
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Try breaking down the factorials to the least one of each type and then working with the fractions.  For example, you have $n!$, $(n-1)!$, and $(n-2)!$.  Break $n!$ down to $n(n-1)(n-2)!$ and $(n-1)!$ down to $(n-1)(n-2)!$.  Do the same for the other types.  This will help you get common denominators and help with simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

From the Pascal's triangle, $$\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{n-1}{k}+\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$$
and$$\dbinom{n-1}{k} = \dbinom{n-2}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-2}{k}$$
$$\rightarrow \dbinom{n}{k}-\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}-\dbinom{n-2}{k-1}=\dbinom{n-1}{k}-\dbinom{n-2}{k-1} = \dbinom{n-2}{k}$$